# Empty fields validation doesn`t work in Struts 2

Tags: java, spring, jsp, validation, struts2

I'm trying use validation on my form and I did all things in the samples and googled many times to find solution but unfortunately I couldn't solve my problem.

**My problem is:**

When I click on submit button with empty filed it register empty to database and validation doesn't work !

I'm using Struts2, Tomcat7, jdk7, Spring4, Hibernate3, and Sitemesh 2.4.2

Can any body help me please ?

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC  
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"  
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">  
  
<struts>  
  
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"/>  
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="xhtml"/>  
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>  
    <!--<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />-->  
  
  
    <package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">  
        <action name="state2CityAction" class="state2CityAction">  
            <result name="SUCCESS" type="json" />  
        </action>  
    </package>  
  
  
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">  
  
        <interceptors>  
            <interceptor-stack name="myStack">  
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">  
                    <param name="validation.excludeMethods">prepareNewInterView,prepare,list,previous,next,load,delete,prepareNewPersonnel,loadPayments,loadTeacherSalary,  
                        searchInterViewed,findActives,findFrozen,findCanceled,findCanceled,findEducated,searchStudentBaseGroupLesson,prepareSearchStudentPayments,loadPersonnel4FishRegister,  
                        prepareGroups4Score,prepareSearchStudentStatus,loadPersonnelFullPayment,listGroupLesson,listGroupLesson4Assign,prepareNewTeacher,listTeacher,prepareSearchTeacherSalary,find,  
                        prepareSearchPersonnelSalaryRedirect,prepareSearchCostsPaymentRedirect,prepareSearchTeacher2AssignAccountNumber,createOtherRedirect,  
                        prepareSearchPersonnel2AssignAccountNumber,listHesabCari,updateInterViewed,loadTeacherPaymentDetails4Edit,loadTeacherFullPayment,  
                        loadTeacherPaymentDetails4Delete,prepareSearchPersonnelSalaryRedirect</param>  
                </interceptor-ref>  
            </interceptor-stack>  
        </interceptors>  
  
  
        <default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>  
        <default-action-ref name="index" />  
  
        <global-results>  
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>  
        </global-results>  
  
     <action name="listBank" class="bankInfoAction" method="list">  
            <result name="success">/listBank.jsp</result>  
        </action>  
  
        <action name="createBank" class="bankInfoAction" method="create">  
            <result name="success">/listBank.jsp</result>  
            <result name="input">/createBank.jsp</result>  
  
        </action>  
  
  
        <action name="updateBank" class="bankInfoAction" method="update">  
            <result name="input">/updateBank.jsp</result>  
            <result name="success">/listBank.jsp</result>  
        </action>  
  
        <action name="deleteBankInfo" class="bankInfoAction" method="delete">  
        <result name="input">/deleteBank.jsp</result>  
        <result name="success">/listBank.jsp</result>  
        </action>  
  
        <action name="load2EditBank"  class="bankInfoAction" method="load">  
            <result name="success">/editBank.jsp</result>  
        </action>  
  
        <action name="load4DeleteBank"  class="bankInfoAction" method="load">  
            <result name="success">/deleteBank.jsp</result>  
        </action>
```

**`BankInfoAction-validation.xml`:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"  
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">  
<validators>  
    <field name="bankInfo.bankName">  
        <field-validator type="required">  
            <message key="errors.required"/>  
        </field-validator>  
    </field>  
     
</validators>
```

This is my Entity

**`BankInfo.java`:**

```
    @Entity  
public class BankInfo {  
  
    @Id  
    @TableGenerator(name = "ct_key", table = "keys_tbl", allocationSize = 70, initialValue = 11)  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ct_key")  
    long id;  
    String bankName;  
   
    public BankInfo() {  
    }  
  
    public BankInfo(String bankName) {  
        this.bankName = bankName;  
  
  
    public long getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
  
    public void setId(long id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
  
    public String getBankName() {  
        return bankName;  
    }  
  
    public void setBankName(String bankName) {  
        this.bankName = bankName;  
    }  
  
    public String toString(){  
        return bankName  ;  
    }  
  
}
```

My Action

**`BankInfoAction.java` :**

```
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;  
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;  
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ParameterAware;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;  
  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Map;  
  
@Component  
public class BankInfoAction extends ActionSupport implements ParameterAware,ModelDriven {  
  
    @Autowired  
    BankInfoService bankInfoService;  
    BankInfo bankInfo = new BankInfo();  
    List<BankInfo> banks = new ArrayList<BankInfo>();  
    Map<String, String[]> request;  
  
    public String create(){  
        bankInfoService.save(bankInfo);  
        list();  
        return "success";  
    }  
  
  
    public String update(){  
        bankInfoService.update(bankInfo);  
        list();  
        return "success";  
    }  
  
  
    public String delete(){  
        bankInfoService.delete(bankInfo);  
        list();  
        return "success";  
    }  
  
  
    public String list(){  
        banks = bankInfoService.list();  
        return "success";  
  
    }  
  
  
    public String load(){  
        bankInfo = bankInfoService.load(bankInfo.getId());  
        return "success";  
    }  
  
  
    public String cancel(){  
        return "success";  
    }  
  
  
    public BankInfoService getBankInfoService() {  
        return bankInfoService;  
    }  
  
    public void setBankInfoService(BankInfoService bankInfoService) {  
        this.bankInfoService = bankInfoService;  
    }  
  
    public BankInfo getBankInfo() {  
        return bankInfo;  
    }  
  
    public void setBankInfo(BankInfo bankInfo) {  
        this.bankInfo = bankInfo;  
    }  
  
    public List<BankInfo> getBanks() {  
        return banks;  
    }  
  
    public void setBanks(List<BankInfo> banks) {  
        this.banks = banks;  
    }  
  
    public Map<String, String[]> getRequest() {  
        return request;  
    }  
  
    public void setRequest(Map<String, String[]> request) {  
        this.request = request;  
    }  
  
  
    @Override  
    public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> maps) {  
        request = maps;  
    }  
  
    @Override  
    public Object getModel() {  
        return bankInfo;  
  
    }  
}
```

**`createBank.jsp` :**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>  
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Create Bank </title>  
</head>  
<body>  
  
     <s:form action="createBank" method="Post" validate="true">  
            <table style="border: 1px solid #C1D0C8;" align="center" bgcolor="#f4f7f5" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" height="320"  
                   width="550">  
            <tr>  
            <td align="center" valign="top">  
            <table border="0" width="95%">  
                <div class="divForms">  
                <div class="item">  
                    <div class="label">  
                        <span><s:text name="Bank.Name"/></span>  
                        <span style="color:red;"> * </span>  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="control">  
                        <s:textfield name="bankName" cssClass="normal_input" theme="simple" />  
                    </div>  
                </div>  
  
                       
                    <div class="But">  
                        <s:submit type="submit" cssClass="gradient-button"  name="newsletter_submit" id="newsletter_submit" key="Save" theme="simple"/>  
                        <s:submit type="submit" cssClass="Cancel" name="newsletter_submit" id="newsletter_submit" key="Cancel" theme="simple"/>  
                    </div>  
  
            </div>  
  
            </table>  
                </tr>  
            </table>  
  
            </s:form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**This is my lib:**

[image]

And another thing is `BankInfoAction-validation.xml`  and `BankInfoAction.java` are in the same directory.

Comment: That's an insane number of exclude methods. Consider organizing it differently.

Comment: Lol @excludes, but +1 for putting nice effort in your first question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<field name="bankName">  
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">  
        <message key="errors.required"/>  
    </field-validator>  
</field>
```

because this field is populated.

The [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) puts the model on the `top` of the `valueStack`. So, you should not worry about setting values.

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: `requered` validator doesn't check for empty string, only for null but `requiredstring` checks both.

Comment: let me explain again first of all I've created Bank form just with 1 textfield (bankName as string) and I've tried to validate textfield with xml validation as you see and after I submited it and without receiveing any error it was sent to success page. and now I added another Textfield named branchCode (int) now when I submit the form  without any entrance  it is  submitted without any error while I'm trying to write string in int textfield the form doesn't submit and it doesn't show any error message

Comment: Create `branchCode` property in the `BankInfo` class which is a model.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days I could finally solve my problem with my teacher's help :
I did all config for validation as you see but:
the first problem was : validatoin didn't work after submit >> my struts version was  struts2-core-2.3.14.3.jar I changed it to struts2-core-2.3.15.x.jar and it worked :)

the second problem was : after submitting validation message wasn't displyed >>> after 1 day i found the solution >>>>> problem was theme="simple" in my textfields I changed it to theme="css_xhtml"